# DIP Switch Connection to I2C EEPROM

Tags: switches

I have a Address Select pins (A0, A1, A2) for I2C Serial EEPROM. These 3 lines enables 8 different addresses for IC. What I want is to connect these lines to DIP switch, so I can manually change addresses. Can I connect those lines from dipswitch directly to GND and VCC or I need pull-up/pull-down resistors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either use pull-up resistors and use the DIP switches to pull down to ground, or use pull-down resistors and use the DIP switches to pull up to Vcc.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbNmjA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you do not pull (up|down) the address lines will be floating when the switch is open, which means arbitrary addresses will be in effect due to noise on the open, typically high-impedance address sense lines.

Comment: Well, that depends on the specific IC. Some are fine with floating address pins.

Comment: @Passerby Generic question, hence most generally applicable answer.